# Copy constructor for class with pointers and structures

Tags: c++, pointers, structure, copy-constructor, deep-copy

I have the following query on copy constructor and assignment constructor for a class with both structures & pointers member variables.

Here is my class

```
class myClass{                                        
       public:      
         Calculator mCalc;      // Calculator is a class that I defined elsewhere

         struct Sstatus{
             bool add_flag;
             int error_code;
             CvMat* matrix;      // I am using OpenCV here for matrix handle 
             double params[6];
         }; 

        // class function
        myClass(void);
       ~myClass(void);

       protected:
              int index;
              BasedClass*  interface;
              CvMat* matrix_int;
       private:
              int calc_index;
              bool* done;
};
```

And my class function is as follows

```
myClass::myClass(void):mCalc(0),
                       index(0),
                       matrix_int(0),
                       calc_index(0),
                       done(0)
{
        interface = new DerivedClass();     // derived class is extended by the base class
}

myClass::~myClass(void){
        delete interface;
}

// defining copy constructor
myClass::myClass(const myClass& o):mCalc(o.mCalc),
                                   index(o.index),
                                   calc_index(o.calc_index),
                                   done(o.done)
{
          // assigning new memory for member pointers for copying
              matrix_int = new CvMat();
              *matrix_int = o.matrix_int;
              interface = new DerivedClass(); 
              *interface = o.interface;
              done = new bool();
              *bool = o.done;
}

// defining assignment operator
myClass::myClass& operator=(const myClass& o)
{
        if(this != &o) 
        {
              mCalc = o.mCalc;
              index = o.index;
              calc_index = o.calc_index;

          // assigning new memory for member pointers for copying
              matrix_int = new CvMat();
              *matrix_int = o.matrix_int;
              interface = new DerivedClass(); 
              *interface = o.interface;
              done = new bool();
              *bool = o.done;

        }

        return *this;

}
```

A few questions I have

1. Is this how copy constructors and assignment operators should be coded? for member pointers and arrays, how should it be done
2. I do not really quite get the difference between assignment and copy constructor for pointer members. It looks similar to me
3. If we want to define a copy constructor and assignment constructor for the structure, how should it be done?

Thanks

Additional questions: If I have used new in my copy constructor, would I be require to delete it in the destructor?

Comment: No, this is not how you should be writing resource owning classes, use smart pointers (`unique_ptr`) to manage the dynamically allocated members. You don't see the difference between copy assignment and copy construction because you're leaking the memory that your data members are already pointing to in case of the assignment operator. Read the [copy and swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom), this should be how you implement copy constructor/copy assignment operator in most cases.

Comment: Never seen a pointer to a `bool`. Why that?

Comment: @Praetorian Stop saying he should use smart pointers when he wants to manage memory dynamically. This is not industry or whatever...

Comment: @nbro Yep, great advice, good job. Keep it up.

Comment: @Praetorian He probably does not know yet what smart pointers are. Smart pointers are nice, but, if ones studies C/C++ for the first time, it's good he understands also the use of DMA, otherwise it would be better to study another programming language...

Comment: @nbro: If you think pointer to bool as a private class member is not an indication of a badly broken design, I have to agree with Praetorian's  comment above :-)

Comment: `*bool = o.done;` ??

Comment: @nbro - `if ones studies C/C++ for the first time`  Which one is it, C or C++?  Two different languages, with different ways of accomplishing things.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie C++ is called like that for a reason. They are different, but they also have a lot in common.

Comment: @Praetorian: Do not have much experience with smart pointer. Will try to look up on it

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is design your class so that it does not require any user-defined copy-constructor, assignment-operator or destructor. Then there is no chance that you can make mistakes in your code for those functions. Further, the implicitly-generated move constructor will work.

Let's fix your class to work this way. There are four pointers we have to deal with:

```
bool* done;
```

This is easy enough, just change to `bool done;` and its initializer should be `false`. Set to `true` when needed.

```
CvMat* matrix_int;
CvMat* matrix;
```

In your existing code you copy a matrix just by using `CvMat`'s assignment operator, and you default-construct them. If that is actually correct then you can fix this just by changing to `CvMat matrix;` and `CvMat matrix_int;`.

```
BasedClass*  interface;
```

Here there is a bit of a problem - since you have customized copy behaviour here (creating a new DerivedClass then doing operator=) there's no standard wrapper for that.

You could make a little helper class for managing this pointer. You have to write copy-constructors etc. for this, but then that code is self-contained, you don't have to write a bunch of useless boilerplate code for the remainder of your class.

Note - using `operator=` to copy the derived class is suspicious.  That will only work if all of the objects are derived from `DerivedClass` , in which case you may as well use `DerivedClass` as the type.

Comment: Just a query. Does this means that by having a class that is devoid of pointer member variables, you do not neccessary need(i know that the C++ gives a default copy constructor) to code for a copy constructor?

Comment: If all member variables (and base classes) have value semantics then the class as a whole also will